# Property 'self.attributedString' not initialized at super.init call - Swift

Tags: swift, init

This is my code:

```
 private var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString
      internal var mode: EditingMode
      public var editor: Editor
    
      override public init() {
        self.attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        mode = EditingMode.none
        super.init()// Error: Property 'self.editor' not initialized at super.init call
      }
    
      init(_ editor: Editor) {
        self.editor = editor
        super.init()//Error: Property 'self.attributedString' not initialized at super.init call
      }
```

I need to pass editor as parameter in init(), so I created a init(_ editor: Editor), but I get these two errors on super.init():

1. Error: Property 'self.editor' not initialized at super.init call
2. Error: Property 'self.attributedString' not initialized at super.init call

Comment: The rule is crystal clear: [*Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties can’t be left in an indeterminate state.*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID204)Initialize the properties according to the error messages

Comment: @vadian So you mean that I do like this:  

  init(_ editor: Editor) {
    self.editor = editor
    self.attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    mode = EditingMode.none
    super.init()
  } ?

Comment: @sdevdev Correct — you need to ensure all instance variables have a value assigned to them before you can call `super.init()`.

Comment: @ItaiFerber How do I pass self.editor = editor in  override public init() {} for this error: Property 'self.editor' not initialized at super.init call?

Comment: @sdevdev You can't directly do that. Unfortunately, in `init()` you need to set `editor` to some default value you don't get from anywhere else. If there is no `Editor` which can work this way, you will need to make the `editor` property optional (and assign it a default value of `nil`). Can you edit your question to add a bit more information about `editor` and how you expect to use it? Is one required?